# How do I check to find gap in vertices or edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I added thickness to a layer of a top, so it could be an item of clothing. But I need to optimize it by selecting the outer faces only (so that I can select the inverse and then shrink the inner faces a little). So I created seams along the top's upper edge, the bottom edge and for each sleeve hole.

The problem is, there are gaps in this mesh (downloaded it and don't know where they are exactly). So what happens is the outer and inner edges get selected, when only the outer faces should (I hover then press "L" to try to select all faces within the seams). I have looked closely and I know that some parts of the top are separate, there are tiny gaps along the edges under the arms. So I have been manually trying to join all vertices I see that are close to where the gap is. I haven't been able to join them all (I select each vertex and then press "f" and this draws a line between them. Then after they are all filled, I add a fill between all edges.) But the problem is, I can't tell where they are all at. So this problem of pressing L does not recognize the boundaries of the seams.

Is there any way to select the whole top check automatically for gaps? I already tried Mesh-->Clean up-->Fill holes, Degenerate dissolve, and Delete loose. But this did not enable me to select only the faces within the seams. I could try to manually select them, but that would be very cumbersome, plus I feel I should make the entire top a whole piece so that that item of clothing is proper. But how? Or if you have any other strategies to solve this problem. Thank you.

This is one area I put a seam.
[image: This is one place where the seam was drawn]

This shows the thickness, just for illustrative purposes.
[image: This is the highlighted edge]

This is what happens when I hover and then press "L". It should only select the outer faces, but selects part inner, part outer.
[image: Selects too much]

Comment: In Edge mode, possibly,  Select menu > All by Trait  >  Non-Manifold, and its 'Adjust Last Operation' panel.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I'll try this and let you know.